# How can I scrollIntoView/focus without the smooth scrolling animation? like focusing instantly on an element

Tags: javascript

I've tried setting `behavior: 'instant'` in the `scrollIntoView` options, but it didn't work, and also `preventScroll: false` for `focus` options, but it still scrolls smoothly to reach the element

on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus in the last code snippet, it behaves like what I want, it instantly focuses on the element, without the scrolling animation, but for me, it always scrolls smoothly until it reaches the element, how can I disable that scrolling animation?

```
function showNextPage() {
    let currPage = parseInt(pageCounter.textContent);
    let target = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${currPage + 1}"]`);
    target.focus({ preventScroll: false }); // ❌ DIDN'T WORK
}

function showNextPage() {
    let currPage = parseInt(pageCounter.textContent);
    let target = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${currPage + 1}"]`);
    target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'instant' }); // ❌ DIDN'T WORK
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollIntoView` with no parameter should scroll instantly.

```
function showNextPage() {
    let currPage = parseInt(pageCounter.textContent);
    let target = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${currPage + 1}"]`);
    target.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Also, you should remove [`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) if you have any in your element's CSS. That could also cause smooth scrolling.

Comment: It should but in my case, it doesn't, that's why I added the behavior option

Comment: @SMH do you have `scroll-behavior: smooth` on the body element's CSS? If you do, that could also cause smooth scrolling

Comment: I don't have any scroll-behavior in my CSS, but I've just commented out the bootstrap link and it's like it fixed it :s, though I need bootstrap, how can I disable that?

Comment: oh nevermind, I had to add `!important` to my scroll-behavior to override it, it's fixed now

Comment: Great, I will update my answer then